Are questions about APA formatting on-topic?
I have a question relating to the proper formatting for multi-paragraph block quotes under APA-7. This would appear to fall under "usage", but I know that StackExchange communities tend to be very specific about what is and isn't on-topic for them, so I thought I'd ask first.
If this question is off-topic, where should I ask it instead? Preferably, this would be somewhere else on the StackExchange network; Quora is an AI-ridden cesspit, and Reddit isn't always good for useful answers either.

No, not on-topic here.
Our topics are


Word choice and usage
Grammar
Etymology (history of words’ development)
Dialect differences
Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
Spelling and punctuation


Note that usage goes with word choice: how to use a word you've chosen.
Writing's topics are


Non-fiction, technical, scholarly, journalistic, or professional blog writing, including the presentation of examples, charts, and diagrams.
Writing fiction, poetry, scripts, or song lyrics.
General copywriting, style, and organization.
Questions asking for help expressing a concept or an idea, within limits.
The publishing and editing process itself.
Questions about specialized writing tools.


Your question falls under "General copywriting, style and organisation," and should be asked on writing.se. They even have a tag for APA.

May also fit [academia.se].
